# get start time of yesterday in unix time stamp(php)

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime

How i can get yesterday time in Unix time stamp format ?

I want to get start time of yesterday for example :

**2016:12:25 00:00:00**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you yesterday's timestemp

**For yesterday date**

```
echo "Yesterday date".time() - 86400; //this will take current time
```

**For last day from given day**

```
$inputedDate = "2016:12:25 00:00:00"; // you can pass date you want
$yesterdayDate = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($inputedDate)-86400);
echo $yesterdayDate;
```

Comment: This wont work when the clock is switched as some times you can have an extra hour or be missing an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You just subtract it by 1 day by passing `strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('datetime'))` to your `date()` function after your format

```
echo date( 'U', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('2016:12:25 00:00:00')) );
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/704433)

Comment: http://www.epochconverter.com/                                                                    it says : GMT: Fri, 23 Dec 2016 23:00:00 GMT

Comment: @addadsaasddasdas that converter is wrong see this
https://gyazo.com/7773c2df60be4e152ef352e39c6b2830
https://gyazo.com/66c46e94b65341f4b2fc06d19a2451d2, you are passing different timestamp. not the timestamp came from my php fiddle